# How to animate the custom vertical slider Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently on click of next and prev, the height of the list is adjusting. Instead of increasing and decreasing the height, i want to replace the current content with new set of content.

Expectation:

1. if I click on next/ prev, current visible list should replace with the new set of items with some slide animation.
2. Also every time I need to display 3 items, in current scenario once the next/prev iteration is completed, only 2 items are getting visible.

This is what I tried:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#list li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#list li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#next').click(function () {
        x= (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;
        $('#list li:lt('+x+')').show();
         $('#prev').show();
        if(x == size_li){
            $('#next').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        x=(x-3<0) ? 3 : x-3;
        $('#list li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
        $('#next').show();
        if(x < 3){
            $('#prev').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle:

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ty0vrb7m/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached the problem a bit differently. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2bx1wsp/1/).

The gist of my solution is that I've used jQuery's `animate` function to do the smooth scrolling effect:

```
$('ul').animate({
    scrollTop: $('ul').scrollTop() + height_to_show
}, 500);
```

One catch, however, is that the `ul` and the `li` elements need to have **fixed heights**. These heights are calculated internally based on the following variables set by you:

```
/**
 * Total number of elements in the list
 * @type {Number}
 */
var num_of_elems = 8;

/**
 * Static height of each element (in pixels)
 * @type {Number}
 */
var height_of_elem = 25;

/**
 * Number of elements you want to show in the page
 * @type {Number}
 */
var num_of_elems_to_show = 3;

/**
 * The visible height of the ul
 * @type {Number}
 */
var height_to_show = 0; //calculated internally
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2bx1wsp/2/).

I've added functionality to hide or show the `prev` and `next` button based on the current page being displayed.

```
/**
 * Show or hide the prev and next button depending on the current_page
 */
var show_hide_buttons = function() {
    if (current_page === Math.ceil(num_of_elems / num_of_elems_to_show) - 1) {
        $('#next').hide();
    } else {
        $('#next').show();
    }

    if (current_page === 0) {
        $('#prev').hide();
    } else {
        $('#prev').show();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but can u please hide and show the next and prev buttons based on the length of the list.

Comment: You mean that on the 1st page the `prev` button won't be shown? And similarly for the `next` button on the last page?

Comment: Yes, inital prev button should not shown, and once u reach the limit of the list , then next should not shown

Comment: Check my answer and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a solution, just wanna leave this fiddle as this is another option and little different animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#list li:lt(3)').show();
   
   $('#next').click(function() {
    $('#prev').show();
    var last = $('#list').children('li:visible:last');
    last.nextAll('#list li:lt(3)').toggle(200);
    last.next().prevAll('#list li').hide(200);
    
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($('#list li').last().is(':visible')){
      $this.hide();
    }
 });
  
  $('#prev').click(function() {
   $('#next').show();
    var first = $('#list').children('li:visible:first');
    first.prevAll('#list li:lt(3)').toggle(200);
    first.prev().nextAll('#list li').hide(200)
    
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($('#list li').first().is(':visible')){
      $this.hide();
    }
 });
  
});
```

```css
ul,li,ol{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.l_swiper{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#list{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 117px;
}
#list li{ 
  display: none;
  padding : 10px;
  border-bottom : 1px solid #333;
}
#list li:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 39px;
}
#next{
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top : 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#prev{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #333;
   padding: 10px;
   margin-top : 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="l_swiper">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
</ul>
<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```